# One field per group - Drupal 6 Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a catalog content type. Each catalog will have a shirt and pant fields, year field and catalog name. I have to create a view which lists the catalogs grouped by the year field. I was able to achieve this by using Grouping Field in my style (HTML list). 
I have to have a Facebook comment box per each year (not each content). Is there a way to add that one field per group ?

EDIT: currently I am appending Facebook comments box via jQuery!

Comment: how are you trying to add the facebook comment box?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no way you can have one field per group. 
I had use scripting to achieve this.